# Will Looping a Runnable Cause a Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-management, handler

Hi so I have a fairly large memory leak in my app and I think it's being caused by my Runnables.
Here is an example of the skeleton of the Runnables i use:

```
    private Runnable randomAlienFire = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            /*A Bunch
               of computations
            */

            mainHandler.removeCallbacks(randomAlienFire);
            mainHandler.postDelayed(randomAlienFire, number );

       }
```

When I switch activities I call `mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` and `thread.randomAlienFire = null;` yet I am still leaking the entire Activity. So my question is, is there something in this basic skeleton that is causing a memory leak? Could it be the fact that the handler is calling to itself?

Comment: what computations do you do inside the handler. that might be causing memory leaks

Comment: the computations wouldnt. It's the runnable as a whole im curious about

Comment: from what i see i don't see anything that causes memory leaks. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: what about the fact the this is a non-static inner class?

Comment: its always better to make inner class static. Are you using activity context inside the inner class?. if so in such a case make your class static and hold a weak reference to the activity context.

Comment: yea im using activity context. When I set a runanble to static I cant access the non-static variables of the outer class though. How do I work around this?

Comment: sure there is a work around as i mentioned using a weak reference. would you post the entire code pls for further assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your implementation will definitely cause a memory leak (I just ran into this myself).

The problem is that you have created a circular reference. You have declared your runnable as a non-static inner class, which means that it will automatically maintain a reference to the activity. The runnable itself is a member variable of your activity, which closes the circle. The garbage collector will never be able to free these objects since there will always be a living reference.

Using a static inner class with a weak reference to the activity is the safest way to fix the problem. [You can see a great code example here.](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) If mainHandler is another non-static inner class, it will create a second circular reference for the same reasons so you will have to do the same thing there.

Setting  `mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` and `thread.randomAlienFire = null;`  could also work, but you have to be very careful where you put that code. Perhaps the code is taking a different path than you expect in some cases and missing those calls? [This blog post describes someone else's very similar experience with that approach.](http://blog.blundellapps.com/outofmemory-using-runnables/)

In my case, I was using a runnable to sequence animations on ImageViews. to get rid of the memory leaks, I created a static runnable class to avoid the circular reference. That alone was not enough for me, I also found that the drawable was still retaining a reference to my fragment. calling `myImageView.removeCallbacksAndMessages(arrowAnimationRunnable);` in onDestroy() in my fragment finally solved the leak. here was my solution:

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public static class SafeRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final WeakReference<MyFragment> parentReference;

        public SafeRunnable(MyFragment parent) {
            parentReference = new WeakReference<MyFragment>(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (parentReference != null) {
                final MyFragment parent = parentReference.get();
                if (parent != null) {
                    runWithParent(parent);
                }
            }
        }

        public void runWithParent(MyFragment parent) {

        }
    }


    // This anonymous instance of the new runnable class does not retain a 
    reference to the fragment
    private Runnable arrowAnimationRunnable = new SafeRunnable(this) {

        @Override
        public void runWithParent(MyFragment parent) {

            // ... animation code

            // repeat the animation in 1 second
            parent.myImageView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    };


    private ImageView myImageView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

        // find the image view and kick off the animation after 1 second
        myImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);
        myImageView.postDelayed(arrowAnimationRunnable, 1000);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // It's necessary to remove the callbacks here, otherwise a message will 
        // be sitting in the queue and will outlive the fragment. Because a 
        // reference in that message will still be pointing to the fragment, the 
        // fragment (and everything else) will not be garbage collected
        myImageView.removeCallbacks(arrowAnimationRunnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this answer correct? I know there is memory leak, but I think Java GC can handle circular reference now.

Comment: As I can see, you still has a memory leak with `arrowAnimationRunnable ` because you make non-static anonymous class of `SafeRunnable` which holds reference to parent. You can remove `SaveRunnable` and use simple `Runnable` with `myImageView.removeCallbacks(arrowAnimationRunnable);` in `onDestroyView`. It does the same

Answer (score 3):

By `mainHandler.postDelayed(randomAlienFire, number );` 
you are queueing a task which may have a memory reference. But the activity may become destroyed before the actual works done. That is causing a memory leak for you.

To get rid of this leak, you must call `mainHandler.removeCallbacks(randomAlienFire);` in an appropriate place before destroying activity. For example if your runnable runs from onStart(), you must call `mainHandler.removeCallbacks(randomAlienFire);` in onStop();